# xbacklight : after I execute it, nothing happens and no output is displayed

Tags: command-line, brightness, xbacklight

I want to manipulate my screen brightness using cli. And the most popular solution I found so far is `xbacklight`.
But unfortunately it doesn't work.

I tried executing
`xbacklight -dec 50` but to no avail. I even executed the same command  with `sudo` but again there was no output and nothing changed.

After looking up online, I found that you can manipulate `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` file. So I did the same and sudo edited the file and changed the default value from 201 to 101 and, **it works**. Brightness decreases. But I want it to work from CLI.

I use Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and Nvidia GPU (performance mode)
Please help!

Thank you.

Comment: Do you run on X? Or Wayland?

Comment: @Jos I run on X

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually I got it working by using `light` package and adding myself to video group.

```
sudo gpasswd -a <user> video
light -A 5
```

Make sure to restart your computer after running `gpasswd` command.
ref- [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/eirsm8/cant_change_brightness_xbacklight_isnt_working/),
[light package](https://haikarainen.github.io/light/)